# Permissões de usuário chamando todas as regras a cada acesso

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership, authorization

Tenho um `MyRoleProvider` implementado e o acesso funciona normal, se o usuário logado não tiver a regra cadastrada ele não permite o acesso.

O problema é que a cada acesso a uma action com o atributo de autorização ele pega todas as regras novamente, como temos controle por tela além de módulos cada usuário tem de 80~200 regras.

```
public string[] GetRolesForUser(string login)
    {
        using (Contexto db = new Contexto())
        {
            var usuario = db.Usuario.FirstOrDefault(m => m.DS_USUARIO == login);

            string[] roles = usuario.Regras.Select(m => m.DS_REGRA).ToArray();

            return roles;
        }
    }
```

Notei que na `MyRoleProvider` existe um método chamado `IfUserInRole` onde passa o login e a regra desejada e ao que parece esse método não é chamado pelo atributo de autorização.

Como posso evitar que o `GetRolesForUser` seja chamado a cada requisição?

> Eu sei que eu poderia fazer um atributo customizado do Authorize e
>   fazer a verificação direta, eu já o fiz, somente por conhecimento
>   estou fazendo a pergunta!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Na verdade o que acontece é que o Lazy Load está sendo chamado ao extremo.

Mude para o seguinte:

```
public string[] GetRolesForUser(string login)
{
    using (Contexto db = new Contexto())
    {
        var usuario = db.Usuario.Include(u => u.Regras).FirstOrDefault(m => m.DS_USUARIO == login);

        return usuario.Regras.Select(m => m.DS_REGRA).ToArray();
    }
}
```

Isso faz o banco de dados carregar as regras como um `JOIN` e não como várias sentenças separadas.

Comment: Ótimo, mas acha que compensa trazer todas as regras do mesmo jeito? O método IfUserInRole deveria ser chamado na minha opinião, não sei o motivo dele não ser utilizado.

Comment: `IsInRole` chama `GetRolesForUser`.

Comment: Aliás, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.roleprincipal.isinrole(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Vou dar uma olhada nesse RolePrincipal o meu role provider extendia http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web.ApplicationServices/Security/RoleProvider.cs